# How to log hardware information from azure web roles/web worker?

Tags: asp.net, logging, azure, azure-diagnostics

I need to get hardware information from azure web roles / web worker to monitor it for critical conditionals like high memory/cpu usage.
I tried to use some addons which are provided in the azure gallery like the one from "logentries", but the gallery doesn't support my country yet...

**Is there an other way to get the log information directly?**

Last option would be Azure Diagnostics, but it stores everything in blob storages and I would have to pull everything out there on my own and send it to "manually" to logentries, geckoboard or whatever.

Answer (score 2):

Three good options:

1. Windows Azure Diagnostics.  Yes, it puts everything in table/blob storage which is painful, but there are tools such as [Cerebrata's Azure Management Studio](http://www.cerebrata.com/products/azure-management-studio/introduction) that can help gather and visualize the data.
2. [Application Insights](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn481095.aspx).  This is still in preview, but it provides a very rich application monitoring and alerting platform.
3. The built in [Azure monitoring](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cloud-services-how-to-monitor/).  This is not quite as feature rich as Application Insights, but it is very easy to setup and use and includes monitoring and alerting.

Comment: Thanks for your information. For a simple application I, too, think Application Insight or Azure monitoring seems to be the way to go. In my current case the application is more complex with many instances of azure workers, DB instancesand ques working together. To get a quick overview over all components it would be nice to bring every hardware and log information together at logentries or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

I'm surprised that no one mentioned New Relic.
It has a comparable feature set to Application Insights but should be way more stable since it's not in preview like Insights. (although I am following the development of Insights closely, give it a while and it will be an awesome alternative)